# libconfig++ -stdlib=libc++ Undefined symbols

Tags: c++, c++11, config, libc++, clang++

Attempting to get a very simple example of libconfig++ working.  However I'm encountering the following link error due to the compiler options '-stdlib=libc++' and '-std=c++11'.

**Environment**

Darwin iMac.local 12.2.0

Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0

xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

**Source**

```
  Config cfg;

  cfg.readFile( "example.cfg" );

  string value = "";

  const string& key = "application.base";

  cfg.lookupValue( key, value );
```

**Build**

clang++ -o main main.cpp -lconfig++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11

**Error**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "libconfig::Config::lookupValue(char   const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,   std::__1::allocator<char> >&) const", referenced from:  
      libconfig::Config::lookupValue(std::__1::basic_string<char,   std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,   std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&)   const in main-mFa01w.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang:   error:   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that this member function:

```
libconfig::Config::lookupValue(const std::string& path, std::string& value) const;
```

was compiled with `-stdlib=libc++` (likely as an inline, but I'm guessing).  And that it in turn calls this member function:

```
libconfig::Config::lookupValue(char const* path, std::string& value) const
```

However this latter function was not compiled with `-stdlib=libc++`.

The most probable fix is to recompile libconfig++ with `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: Yep, I've attempted multiple build configurations with no luck. So I chickened out and came running to SO. Thx for your time.

Comment: Try "nm -gm libconfig++.dylib |c++filt |grep lookupValue".  If you see "__1" libconfig++.dylib has libc++ symbols in it.  Otherwise it has libstdc++ symbols in it.